# Button Performclick another Tab Page

Tags: vb.net

Why this code doesn't work?

`BttGamblerInput.PerformClick()`

I tried to activate the code but the button is in a Tab Page. So how do they make it work?

Tab Control 1 - Tab Page 6 (Index 2)

Comment: If you ensure that the `TabPage` containing `BttGamblerInput` has been displayed to the user first, does that code do what you expect?  Controls on a `TabPage` aren't actually created until the `TabPage` is selected.  Clicking a control that doesn't exist won't do anything.  You have to make sure that the control has been created.

Comment: Also, stating the obvious, does clicking `BttGamblerInput` itself do what you expect?

Comment: Tab Page 6 (Index 2). - tab control 1.

Answer (score 1):

whatever is in BttGamblerInput code make it as a sub. 
whenever you want to call the code just call the sub